# Using ArrayCamera causes objects outside of 1 unit disappear

Tags: javascript, three.js

When I use a PerspectiveCamera, the objects are rendered properly. However, when I wrap the PerspectiveCamera in an ArrayCamera and use the ArrayCamera, objects outside of 1 unit from 0,0,0 seem to disappear.

```
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera();
camera.viewport = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
camera.position.set(0, 10, 40)
arrayCamera.cameras.push(camera);
scene.add(camera);
```

[Here's a video of the rendering with PerspectiveCamera](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard17/uploads/threejs/original/2X/b/bdf17bc7df60c250f91275248bbd16bd790832a4.mp4)

[With ArrayCamera wrapping the PerspectiveCamera](https://aws1.discourse-cdn.com/standard17/uploads/threejs/original/2X/b/bdf17bc7df60c250f91275248bbd16bd790832a4.mp4)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `ArrayCamera`, you have to be aware to handle view frustum culling in a special way.

Normally, view frustum culling is used to discard objects from rendering if they are outside of the camera's view frustum. The frustum is derived from the camera's projection and view matrix. When using `ArrayCamera` like in your code, both matrices are not properly set and thus improper view frustum culling breaks your scene. There are to ways to fix this issue:

- Disable view frustum culling for your objects by seeting `Object3D.frustumCulled` to `false`.
- Define a 3D transformation and projection matrix for your instance of `ArrayCamera`. I've implemented this in the following live example:

```js
var scene = new THREE.Scene();
var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000);

var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);

var geometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry();
var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({
  color: 0x00ff00
});
var cube = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
//cube.frustumCulled = false; // FIX 
scene.add(cube);

camera.position.z = 10;
camera.updateMatrixWorld();
camera.viewport = new THREE.Vector4(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);

var arraycamera = new THREE.ArrayCamera();
arraycamera.cameras.push(camera);
arraycamera.position.copy( camera.position ); // FIX 
arraycamera.projectionMatrix.copy( camera.projectionMatrix ); // FIX 

var animate = function() {
  requestAnimationFrame(animate);

  if (cube.position.x > 5)
    cube.position.x = -1;
  else cube.position.x += 0.1;

  renderer.render(scene, arraycamera);
};

animate();
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/three@0.121.1/build/three.js"></script>
```

As you can see, I've just copied over the values from your actually camera. In context of VR (where `ArrayCamera` is mainly used), you want to combine projection matrices to produce a frustum that covers the left and right eye.

The general idea is to do view frustum culling only once when using `ArrayCamera` (since you perform multiple renderings with a single render pass).